# MongoDB, NodeJs. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB database in localhost. While I type `mongo` in command shell I am getting an **error** in the command shell:

> js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17

Comment: It may mean that your MongoDB server is not running. First, you should run it, and it would work.

Comment: Can you please be a little more detail, how can I run it?

Comment: Yes, I had to run it in another shell by mongod command, then working nicely. Even though I had set the environment variable, I have to recheck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command `mongod` will run the MongoDB server using the default configuration. You can change these configurations by locating the default path of the configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

This will start the mongo server as a service:

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary daemon process for the MongoDB database system is called **mongod**. You need to start this service before making connection attempts.

You can do this in Ubuntu by:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

or,

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Start mongod on system boot by:

```
systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
When running `mongod` command, it mentioned the C:/data/db as `E:/data/db` path.
After I created the folder in mentioned `E:/data/db` path ***it works!***

Answer (score 0):

For windows user

```
1. Type ctrl + r
```

[image: Type ctrl + r]

[image: mongodb server]

```
2. Scroll to mongodb server

3. start the server
```

Comment: If you encoutered any porblem, do comment.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a linux distro? If you do, the solution is a bit annoying as you have to do it everytime you start your pc. The solution is:

1. Type "mongo" and "mongod" once in the terminal. It will show an error, don't worry, that's the whole point
2. type this:

   `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`

   `chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

   `sudo service mongod restart`

tip: copy the whole thing and paste on the terminal using ctrl+shift+v. You're welcome :-)